# Error when using ja3transport with Go v1.13 on M2 Mac: 'found packages tls and main in utls

Tags: go

When I try to execute this piece of code with go v1.13 in my m2 mac.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport"
)

func CreateTransport() {
    // Create an http.Transport object which can be used as a parameter for http.Client
    tr, _ := ja3transport.NewTransport("771,4866-4865-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53,23-65281-10-11-35-16-5-13-18-51-45-43-27-17513,29-23-24,0")
    // Set the .Transport member of any http.Client
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    // Make request to website using the new client
    resp, _ := client.Post("https://localhost:8787/index.php", "application/json", strings.NewReader("{\"username\":\"admin\"}"))
    // Print the response
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    println(string(body))
}
func main() {
    CreateTransport()
}
```

I receive the following error:

> ../../../../go/src/github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport/ja3client.go:9:2: found packages tls (alert.go) and main (generate_cert.go) in /Users/aymanboulaichdahhou/go/src/github.com/refraction-networking/utls

I use v1.13 because is the one which the creator of ja3transport recommends for the library.

I tried to execute it with multiple go versions I downloaded the file and used relative paths and absolute ones but nothing worked.

Comment: 1. Use modules (properly). 2. Use Go 1.21. 3. Show your go.mod. 4. Show exactly how you "run" your code. 5. Show the whole FS tree.

Answer (score 1):

> I use v1.13 because is the one which the creator of ja3transport recommends for the library.

I don't see where they do this, but ignore the advice. Go is fully backward compatible.

github.com/refraction-networking/utls [requires Go 1.20 or newer](https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls/blob/v1.5.3/go.mod#L3). [There is a build constraint in generate_cert.go](https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls/blob/v1.5.3/generate_cert.go#L5) that Go 1.13 does not understand.

Comment: The problem is that when I try to install it with go 1.21:

`go install [github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport@latest](http://github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport@latest)`

I receive this error:

`package [github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport](http://github.com/CUCyber/ja3transport) is not a main package`

Comment: It's a library, not a main package. Use `go get` instead. Make sure to [initialize your module](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module#start) before adding the dependency.

Comment: The problem resides in that is no longer suported the get parameter in v1.21: go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
 'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
 To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
 like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
 For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
 or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.`